# How to ping through SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: linux, bash, ping, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

I have some `SOCK5` proxy made through `SSH tunnel` as `127.0.0.1:8080` (8081, 8082, etc). I want to ping a website through different proxies to find which one provides a faster route.

How can I use the `ping` command or similar ones in Ubuntu terminal to do? Ultimately, I wish to write a `bash` script for the whole comparison.

Answer (score 4):

ICMP protocol won't work over SOCKS, but you can employ [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to do TCP ping. Check this [l4ping](https://github.com/tyru/srvtools/blob/master/l4ping) to see how to do that.

Comment: Correct, SOCKS5 only supports TCP and UDP, so you could also theoretically do a UDP ping, but support for UDP seems a bit less reliable in SOCKS servers, probably because it's not often used.

Comment: P.s. ping is ICMP not IGMP

Comment: @Adrien You right, typo fixed

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use ping through a proxyfier (personally I use [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)).